# How to generate a model with a enum type field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I want to generate a model and the corresponding database table in Rails using the generator script. The database table has a field with "enum" type. How can I generate it?

The table’s definition in SQL:

```sql
create table works {
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  nickname varchar(20) not null,
  sex enum('m', 'f') not null
};
```

The Rails generator command:

```sh
script/generator work nickname:string sex:(what should I write here?)
```

Answer (score 58):

Rails 4.1 added [`ActiveRecord::Enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), which emulates enums using an `integer`-type column. You can use them as long as you are willing to change the column type to an integer in the database.

To use these enums, put `integer` in your generate command:

```sh
bin/rails generate Work nickname:string sex:integer
```

Then add a call to `enum` in the generated model file:

```ruby
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum sex: [ :male, :female ]
end
```

See [`Enum`’s documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for more details.

Answer (score 8):

You could just use a string and then add validation on the model like this:

validates_inclusion_of :sex, :in => %w( m f )

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the valid column types are: integer, float, datetime, date, timestamp, time, text, string, binary, and boolean

Try making the column a string and using `validates_inclusion_of`.

Answer (score 2):

Use enum_column to add enum support to active record

https://github.com/mdsol/enum_column